# Наследование C++

Tags: c++

Например, подкласс наследует поля и методы надкласса, а другой класс, наследует поля и методы предыдущего подкласса(который наследует надкласс), будет ли этот под класс наследовать поля и методы надкласса тоже?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C будет иметь доступ к полям и методам класса A?

Comment: попробуйте добавить простую схему в вопрос. что то вроде `A -> B`. где A предок, а B потомок.

Comment: А почему бы нет?

Answer (score 3):

Давайте разберёмся. Начнём с того, что в С++ есть три модификатора доступа к методам и полям класса (`public, private и protected`), а также три различных наследования(`public, private и protected`).

---

Начнём с самого простого. С `public` наследования. Итак пусть класс `B` публично наследуется от класса `A`. Тогда `public` и `protected` методы и поля класса `А` становятся соответствующими полями класса `B`. А `private` поля класса `A` недоступны из класса `B`.

---

`private` наследование. В результате такого наследования `public` и `protected` методы и поля класса `А` становятся `private` для класса `B`. А `private` поля из класса `A` недоступаны в классе `B`

---

Самое редкое `protected` наследование. `private` поля базового класса всё также недоступны из класса наследника. А `protected` и `public` поля базового класса переходят в `protected` поля класса наследника.

То есть на такой вопрос невозможно дать однозначный ответ. Чтобы понять, какие поля и методы будут доступны, нужно определить, какими эти поля являются в классе `A` и какое наследование определено между классами `A` и `B`, а также `B` и `C`.

Ссылки:
[Про модификаторы доступа и наследование](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kktasw36.aspx)
[Пример с последовательным наследованием](http://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=47)

Comment: А `static` и `friend` имеют к этой схеме отношение?

Comment: @0andriy `static` не влияет на наследование, но `static` поле будет общее у класса и его наследника, а друзья класса [не наследуются](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/465sdshe.aspx).